# save children along with parent linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

I have two tables Rule and RuleCondition (one -> many).

people can add conditions at any time.

Suppose initially he adds two conditions.
He can comeback and add another condition also can update the conditions that are already added.

I am able to save the updated conditions, but not able to insert the extra condition he added.
Below is my code, and it is failing at

```
rule.RuleConditions.Add(oRuleCon); -- Entity set was modified during enumaration
```

If I use the approach

```
oAngieCtxt.RuleConditions.InsertOnSubmit(oRuleCon);
```

it is not at all inserting the data.

can somebody advise how to handle?

```
public ActionResult saveMetricRule(Rule rule)
    {
        bool IsNew = rule.RuleId == 0;

        using (NewAngieDataContext oAngieCtxt = new NewAngieDataContext(new CSConfigurationMgr().GetConnectionString(ConnectionStringKey.Angie)))
        {
            if (IsNew)
                oAngieCtxt.Rules.InsertOnSubmit(rule);
            else
            {
                RuleCondition oRuleCon = null;
                foreach (RuleCondition childItem in rule.RuleConditions)
                {
                    if (childItem.RuleConditionId == 0)
                    {
                        oRuleCon = new RuleCondition();
                        oRuleCon.Points = childItem.Points;
                        oRuleCon.ConditionValue = childItem.ConditionValue;
                        oRuleCon.ToOperatorId = childItem.ToOperatorId;
                        oRuleCon.Sort = childItem.Sort;
                        rule.RuleConditions.Add(oRuleCon);
                  //   oAngieCtxt.RuleConditions.InsertOnSubmit(oRuleCon);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        oRuleCon =
                            oAngieCtxt.RuleConditions
                            .Where(CON => CON.RuleConditionId == childItem.RuleConditionId)
                            .FirstOrDefault();

                        oRuleCon.Points = childItem.Points;
                        oRuleCon.ConditionValue = childItem.ConditionValue;
                        oRuleCon.ToOperatorId = childItem.ToOperatorId;
                        oRuleCon.Sort = childItem.Sort;
                    }
                }

                oAngieCtxt.Rules.Attach(rule);
                oAngieCtxt.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, rule);
            }
            oAngieCtxt.SubmitChanges();
        }

        return this.Json(new
        {
            msg = "Successful save.",
            ruleId = rule.RuleId
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't add an item to a list that you're enumerating over. Since you're looping over the `rule.RuleConditions`, you can't add to it inside the `foreach` loop. Instead, you can add to a temporary list and then add all items from that list to the `rule.RuleConditions` after the `foreach`.

```
var newRuleConditions = new List<RuleCondition>();
foreach (RuleCondition childItem in rule.RuleConditions)
{
  if (childItem.RuleConditionId == 0)
  {
    oRuleCon = new RuleCondition();
    oRuleCon.Points = childItem.Points;
    oRuleCon.ConditionValue = childItem.ConditionValue;
    oRuleCon.ToOperatorId = childItem.ToOperatorId;
    oRuleCon.Sort = childItem.Sort;
    //add to temporary list
    newRuleConditions.Add(oRuleCon);
    oAngieCtxt.RuleConditions.InsertOnSubmit(oRuleCon);
  }
  else
  {
    ...
  }
}
//add all new rule conditions
rule.RuleConditions.AddRange(newRuleConditions);
```